# Size of Union of 2 Disjoint Sets

Tags: real-analysis

This problem is taken from *Bartle and Sherbert*. The theorem in the book is stated as the following:

If ${A}$ is a set with $m$ elements and ${B}$ is a set with $n$ elements and if
${A} \cap {B} = \phi$,  then ${A} \cup {B}$ has $m + n$ elements.

The solution given in the books is the following:

[image]

But unfortunately I'm not getting the proof. Can someone please guide me how to solve this prove?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the proof is wrong, or you perhaps miscopied. Also, I would prefer not to use "$\ldots$" in a formal proof.
Instead, I would write
$$ h(i)=\begin{cases}f(i)&i\in N_m\\g(i-m)&i\notin N_m\end{cases}$$
First check: Is this definition ok? If $i\in N_m$, then $f(i)$ is defined and $\in A\subseteq A\cup B$, so the upper branch is fine.
If $i\notin N_m$, I suppose that the arithmetic within $\Bbb N$ is complete available. Then it follows that $i-m$ is defined and is $\in N_n$ for $i\in N_{n+m}\setminus N_m$. So $g(i-m)$ is defined as is $\in B\subseteq A\cup B$. So

> $h$ is a map from $N_{n+m}$ to $A\cup B$.

Suppose $h(i)=h(j)$. Then either

- $i,j\in N_m$ and $f(i)=f(j)$. As $f$ is injective, we conclude $i=j$.
- or $i,j\notin N_m$ and $g(i-m)=g(j-m)$. As $g$ is injective, we conclude $i-m=j-m$ and then $i=j$.
- or $i\in N_m$ and $j\notin N_m$ or vice versa. But then $h(i)=f(i)\in A$ and $h(j)=g(j-m)\in B$, so $h(i)=h(j)\in A\cap B$, which is absurd

So

> $h$ is injective

Finally, for $a\in A$, there exists $i\in N_m$ with $f(i)=a$; then $h(i)=a$. And for $b\in B$, there exists $j\in N_n$ with $g(j)=b$; then $j+m\in N_{n+m}\setminus N_m$ and $h(j+m)=g(j)=b$. So

> $h$ is surjective.

Comment: Thanks! Extremely thoroughly written proof! Also, updated the question but putting the snap from the text.